# How to connect Entity framework to informix database over SQLI?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, protocols, informix, provider

I recently started working at a place that uses an informix db. I think they're using version 11.7. there might be problems regarding the policy of the institution if we try to enable the DRDA protocol on the server. So, is there any other way or workaround to connect entity framework to the informix server that doesn't necessarily require the enabling of the DRDA protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may change in the future, but at the moment the only EF provider supporting Informix back-end is the IBM Data Server one which requires a DRDA connection.

The Informix one (using SQLI and included in CSDK) does support .NET 4.x but there is no provider for EF yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope it changes in the future